# TypeORM OneToMany creates foreign key column on another entity

Tags: mysql, one-to-many, typeorm

I have three tables: User, UserToken and UserRank.
The relationships between them are:

- For user:

  @OneToMany(() => UserToken, userToken => userToken.user)
  userTokens: UserToken[]

  @ManyToOne(() => UserRank, (userRank) => userRank.id, { onDelete: 'CASCADE', cascade: true })
  rank: UserRank
- For UserToken:

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.id, { onDelete: 'CASCADE', cascade: true })
  user: User
- For UserRank:

  @OneToMany(() => User, user => user.rank)
  user: User[]

The behaviour I want is:

- an user can have a rank, and multiple UserTokens.

The problem is that I've added that UserRank OneToMany relationship and now I have the userRankId also in the UserTokens table, and I don't want this. Can you, please, help me solve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define foreign key constraint with createForeignKeyConstraints option (default: true), you can set it to "false".

```js
import { Entity, PrimaryColumn, Column, ManyToOne } from "typeorm"
import { Person } from "./Person"

@Entity()
export class ActionLog {
    @PrimaryColumn()
    id: number

    @Column()
    date: Date

    @Column()
    action: string

    @ManyToOne((type) => Person, {
        createForeignKeyConstraints: false,
    })
    person: Person
}
```